# Populate Drop Down Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a little bit of help with automatically population drop down menus dynamically.

The code I have written just will not work for me, but it did at first and has now stopped.

Where am I going wrong?

HTML:

```
<form id="booking_form" onsubmit="return checkForm()" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <!-- Select Movie -->
        <span class="label">Movie Name:</span>
        <select name="movie" id="movie_name" onChange="changeday(this.value);">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Movie</option>
            <option value="SW">Star Wars: The Force Awakens</option>
            <option value="WC">Wedding Crashers</option>
            <option value="GD">The Good Dinosaur</option>
            <option value="BR">Battle Royale</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <!-- Select Day -->                     
        <span class="label">Session Day:</span>
        <select name="day" id="session_day">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select a Movie</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var moviesByDays = {
        SW: ["Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday"],
        WC: ["Tuesday", "Tues", "Tues", "Tues"],
        GD: ["Wednesday", "Wed", "Wed", "Wed", "Wed"],
        BR: ["Thursday", "Thurs", "Thurs", "Thurs", "Thurs"]
}

function changeday(value) {
    if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("session_day").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
    else {
        var catOptions = "";
        for (session_dayId in moviesByDay[value]) {
            daysOptions += "<option>" + moviesByDays[value][session_dayId] + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("session_day").innerHTML = daysOptions;
    }
}
```

How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If I only had a dime each time this question was asked....

Comment: maybe a quick diagram of the drop downs you want will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have made some mistakes in variable and assignments. Use below in `Script` tag:

```
  var moviesByDays = {
        SW: ["Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday"],
        WC: ["Tuesday", "Tues", "Tues", "Tues"],
        GD: ["Wednesday", "Wed", "Wed", "Wed", "Wed"],
        BR: ["Thursday", "Thurs", "Thurs", "Thurs", "Thurs"]
  }


  function changeday(value) {
    var daysOptions = []; //That will Clear first selection on every new selection
    if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("session_day").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
    else {
        var catOptions = "";
        for (session_dayId in moviesByDays[value]) {                
            daysOptions += "<option>" + moviesByDays[value][session_dayId] + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("session_day").innerHTML = daysOptions;
    }
 }
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/cvfcof8w/)

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!

Comment: Just created a fiddle, fixed this and was going to post the answer; and there you are! lol. Anyway thanks. Hope you got it solved @Lachlan Norris